# Trash applet doesn't show trash from a cifs mount in ubuntu 18.04 why?

Tags: gnome, cifs, 18.04, trash

Trash applet doesn't show trash from a cifs mount

it creates the folder .Trash-1000, the files moved to trash are there but not showed at Trash applet, this happen only ubuntu 18.04, at ubuntu 17.10.1
works fine.